# Can't create or veryHide sheets in existing Excel workbook using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, addition, worksheet

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Excel 2013.
Part of my first VS2013 project (which is an Excel .COM add-in) has a separate Sub called "hidesheets" below.

My questions are: will someone explain why my code doesn't ADD a worksheet, allow me to NAME IT and allow me to make other sheets VERYHIDDEN and offer any advice to get it working please.

I have tried six different variations (commented out in the code block) trawled variously from SO and the web.  Most code examples seem to start by creating an instance of Excel, then a Workbook in the code.  My example has an existing, named, open workbook and a call to this Sub passing the workbook name as a string parameter.  I am an improver in vb.net so my understanding on things is not that well developed.

I do not get any exceptions thrown.  I have checked that the workbook is not protected.

When I extract this code and place it in its own project it runs and works OK.

```
'Placed at top of Class
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Diagnostics


Public Sub hidesheets(ByVal wbnme As String)

Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks(wbnme)
Dim newws As Excel.Worksheet

With wbk
    'Add a dummy sheet first to veryHide other sheets (will add check for already exists later)

    '============THIS DOESN'T ADD A NEW SHEET (6 X DIFFERENT ATTEMPTS)================
    '=================================================================================

    Debug.Print(wbk.Sheets.Count)

    'newws = wbk.Worksheets.Add
    'newws = CType(.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    'newws = CType(wbk.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    'newws = CType(.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    newws = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    newws.Name = "Dummy"

    Debug.Print(wbk.Sheets.Count)

    '==================================================================================


    '============THIS DOESN'T PRODUCE VERYHIDDEN SHEETS ===============================
    '==================================================================================

    'Make other sheets xlVeryHidden
    For Each sht As Excel.Worksheet In .Sheets
        If sht.Name = "Dummy" Then
            'Do nothing it's the dummy sheet
        Else
            sht.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next sht

    '==================================================================================

  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"When I extract this code and place it in its own project it runs and works OK."*

Comment: @jbutler483 thank you for responding.  Exactly that.  I put this into a new Visual Studio project, added a Form and Button and called it from this button.

Comment: so the code above works?

Comment: Yes it works in this stand-alone way, but the same code not when embedded in my project.  I call it from the WorkbookBeforeSave event.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Have you tested that you have the correct wbk (such as debug.print wbk.Name) and (2) Have you tried doing some other change to the workbook (such as setting some cell value) ?

Comment: I think the last (uncommented out) method could fail if the wbk is not the current workbook: Application.Worksheets should be synonymous with ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(), but you want worksheets of named workbook.

Comment: @JonT thanks for your interest.  Yes, it is looking at the correct workbook and yes edits to the workbook are saved OK.  The last method you mention (and the first actually) are set within a 'With wbk End With' block.